# Custom CSS for MVC PagedList

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, pagedlist

I used PagedList.MVC for my web, but I have some problems with CSS, because pagination on my web looks:

[image: current]

but should looks:

[image: wish]

I'm using bootstrap also with my own css .. so somewhere must be conflict between them. Ican't find where conflict started.
Any idea for custom css? Maybe add some style here:

```
.pagination {
  display: compact;
  padding-left: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.pagination > li {
  display: inline-grid;
}

.pagination > li > a,
.pagination > li > span {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  padding: 0;
  margin-left: -1px;
  line-height: 1.428571429;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #eee;
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
}

.pagination > li:first-child > a,
.pagination > li:first-child > span {
  margin-left: 0;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
  border-top-left-radius: 4px;
}

.pagination > li:last-child > a,
.pagination > li:last-child > span {
  border-top-right-radius: 4px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
}

.pagination > li > a:hover,
.pagination > li > span:hover,
.pagination > li > a:focus,
.pagination > li > span:focus {
  background-color: #eeeeee;
}

.pagination > .active > a,
.pagination > .active > span,
.pagination > .active > a:hover,
.pagination > .active > span:hover,
.pagination > .active > a:focus,
.pagination > .active > span:focus {
  z-index: 2;
  color: #000;
  cursor: default;
  background-color: #428bca;
  border-color: #428bca;
}

.pagination > .disabled > span,
.pagination > .disabled > a,
.pagination > .disabled > a:hover,
.pagination > .disabled > a:focus {
  color: #999999;
  cursor: not-allowed;
  background-color: #eee;
  border-color: #dddddd;
}

.pagination-lg > li > a,
.pagination-lg > li > span {
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.pagination-lg > li:first-child > a,
.pagination-lg > li:first-child > span {
  border-bottom-left-radius: 6px;
  border-top-left-radius: 6px;
}

.pagination-lg > li:last-child > a,
.pagination-lg > li:last-child > span {
  border-top-right-radius: 6px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 6px;
}

.pagination-sm > li > a,
.pagination-sm > li > span {
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.pagination-sm > li:first-child > a,
.pagination-sm > li:first-child > span {
  border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;
  border-top-left-radius: 3px;
}

.pagination-sm > li:last-child > a,
.pagination-sm > li:last-child > span {
  border-top-right-radius: 3px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
}
```

Comment: Can add html code here?

Comment: in Chrome's developer tools you can highlight an element and then look at the computed styles. Pick a property and it'll tell you where it came from - should be fairly easy to work out the conflicts from there.

Comment: I don't find any conflicts with Chrome's developer

Answer (score 1):

Use This css

```
ul
{
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden; /*background-color: #333;*/
}
li
{
    float: left;
    border-right: 1px solid #bbb;
}
li:last-child
{
    border-right: none;
}
li a
{
    display: block;
    color: Black;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
li a:hover:not(.active)
{
    background-color: #4CAF50;
}
.active
{
    background-color: #4CAF50;
}
```